# Linking .so file on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, printing, android-ndk, .so

I'm still new to Android development, so I'm stuck with NDK.

Background: I am trying to connect my app to the printer. For that purpose the vendor gave a sample application which discovers printer and then prints. Right now I am trying to run that sample application but it has a `.so` file and every time I try to run it gives me this error:

```
01-01 17:34:59.618: E/AndroidRuntime(5870): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xyz.epos2_printer-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.xyz.epos2_printer-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libepos2.so"
```

I am using Eclipse not Android Studio (so build.gradle solution won't work for me I suppose). I have searched on this topic but couldn't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check you have added `libepos2.so` file in your project

check the screen shot. [image: in folders mentioned in the screen]

**Step 2**

- Add the following in gradle under default config.

  ndk {
              abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "armeabi", "mips"
          }

  ```
      sourceSets { main { jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
  ```

**Step 3**

Add this in dependency:

```
implementation files('libs/ePOSEasySelect.jar')
implementation files('libs/ePOS2.jar')
implementation files('libs/armeabi/libeposeasyselect.so')
implementation files('libs/armeabi/libeposprint.so')
```

**Step 4**

Add this in gradle.properties:

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Comment: But how to add this in mk file? I am using an app which is eclipse project